# how to make keras set_weights work

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, lstm

I would like to construct an LSTM using the given weights and architecture with the following code (lstm_model_weights is a list of numpy arrays).

```
    lstm_model = Sequential()
    lstm_model.add(LSTM(num_hidden_units, input_shape=input_shape, 
    go_backwards=True, activation='tanh', recurrent_dropout=0.0, 
    implementation=2))
    lstm_model.add(Dropout(0.0))
    lstm_model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
    lstm_model.set_weights(lstm_model_weights)
```

This does not seem to set the weights of lstm_model to lstm_model_weights. When I look at the output of

```
    lstm_model.get_weights()
```

I see different weights from lstm_model_weights. Can anyone help?